# How to extract specific elements of a table

Tags: r

I a new user of R and I am looking for a script to extract specific columns and rows of a table. I have a precipitation file format ".nc" downloaded on Climate Research Unit that has been converted to ".txt". The data are recorded from 1901 to 2014 per months and I would like to have only a table showing data of for instance the year 1988 (where Latitude, Longitude and records of the 12 months will be displayed).Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that you read the dataset using `read.table/read.csv`, we can use `subset` i.e. `subset(yourdata, year==1988)`  It is better to show few lines of your dataset.

Comment: It doesn't matter what your original file formats were. Once you have read the data into R, it should be stored in an R object with a name. Is your data stored in a `data.frame` object?

Comment: Are you sure it's 1901? I though that data set goes back to 1850??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague so it's very difficult to help you. You say you converted your `ncdf` file to a text file. How? What is the format of that file (what is in the rows? columns?)? How are we supposed to know?

Nevertheless, this should get you started.

```
library(ncdf)
url <- "http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/temperature/CRUTEM.4.4.0.0.anomalies.nc"
tf  <- tempfile()
download.file(url, tf, mode="wb")
nc <- open.ncdf(tf)
nc
# [1] "file C:\\Users\\jlh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpgPupyr\\filed2c1853163f has 4 dimensions:"
# [1] "latitude   Size: 36"
# [1] "longitude   Size: 72"
# [1] "time   Size: 1987"
# [1] "field_status_string_length   Size: 1"
# [1] "------------------------"
# [1] "file C:\\Users\\jlh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpgPupyr\\filed2c1853163f has 2 variables:"
# [1] "float temperature_anomaly[longitude,latitude,time]  Longname:temperature_anomaly Missval:-1.00000001504747e+30"
# [1] "char field_status[field_status_string_length,time]  Longname:field_status Missval:NA"


x <- get.var.ncdf(nc, "longitude")
y <- get.var.ncdf(nc, "latitude")
t <- get.var.ncdf(nc, "time")
z <- get.var.ncdf(nc, "temperature_anomaly")
str(z)
#  num [1:72, 1:36, 1:1987] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

So this code downloads the temperature anomalies `ncdf` file from from the Climate Research Unit at the University of East Anglia (http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/data), using the `ncdf` package in R. You can see that this file has attributes `latitude`, `longitude`, `time`, and `status_length`, and two response variables: `temperature_anomaly` and `field_status`.

The calls to `get.var.ncdf(...)` extract the longitude, latitude, and time scales and then the actual data. The latter is in a 3-dimensional matrix, `z` (one dimension for lat, one for long, one for time).

I gather from your question that you want a "table" (not a meaningful idea in R) showing a response (I've chosen temp anomaly for this example), along with lat, long, and date for every combination of lat/long and every month in 1988. But I'm only guessing here, because you really don't tell us much of anything.

So this is really an exercise in converting the matrix `z` into a the format above. We can do this easily using `melt(...)` in the `reshape2` package (read the documentation). The only tricky bit is interpreting `time`. According to the CRU website, time is stored as number of days since 1850-01-01 (where did you get 1900 from??), in increments of 29.5 days (so. one point per month. Lines 2:4 below convert a year (e.g., 1988) into a vector of indexes into the time dimension of `z`.

```
library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
yr   <- 1988
st   <- (yr-1850)*12+1
indx <- st:(st+11)
m <- z[,,indx]
dimnames(m) <- list(x,y,strftime(as.Date("1850-01-01")+t[indx],format="%b-%Y"))
result      <- melt(m, varnames=c("longitude", "latitude", "date"), value.name="temp")
#   longitude latitude     date temp
# 1    -177.5    -87.5 Jan-1988   NA
# 2    -172.5    -87.5 Jan-1988   NA
# 3    -167.5    -87.5 Jan-1988   NA
# 4    -162.5    -87.5 Jan-1988   NA
# 5    -157.5    -87.5 Jan-1988   NA
# 6    -152.5    -87.5 Jan-1988   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thank you dear **jlhoward** for your well detailed answer. I found a solution to my problem and here is the script that I used:

Folder="C:/cru2/Pre/"

file=paste(folder,"Precipitation_1901-2014.txt",sep="")

data=read.table(file,header=T,sep="\t")

years=1901:2014
cumulyears=data[,1:2]

nyr=0
n2=2

for (yrs in annees){
  nyr=nyr+1
  n1=n2+1
  n2=n1+11

  datayrs=cbind(data[,1:2],data[,n1:n2])

  output=paste(folder,yrs,".txt",sep="")

  write.table(datayrs, file = output, append = FALSE,sep = "\t",eol = "\r", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = F,col.names = F)

  row.sums <- apply(data[,n1:n2], 1, sum,na.rm=T)

  cumulyears=cbind(cumulyears,row.sums)

}

colnames(cumulyears)=c("Latitude","Longitude",years)

output=paste(folder,"precipitationyears.txt",sep="")

write.table(cumulyears, file = output, append = FALSE,sep = "\t",eol = "\r", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = F,col.names = T)

I did not try yet what you have proposed but I will do so in a brief delay inshAllah. About your question on how I have converted a ".nc" to ".txt" below is the script I have used. Here is also the Climate Research Unit link where I got my data (http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/hrg/cru_ts_3.23/cruts.1506241137.v3.23/). Thanks again.

library("ncdf")
library("chron")

Folder="C:/cru2"

variable="pre"

periodes1=c(1901,1911,1921,2011)
periodes2=c(2014,1920,1930,2014)

nbyrs=length(periodes1)

for (ip in 1:1){

  name=paste("cru_ts3.23.",periodes1[ip],".",periodes2[ip],".",variable,".dat",sep="")

  years=c(periodes1[ip],periodes2[ip])

  file=paste(folder,name,".nc",sep="")

  x <- open.ncdf("cru_ts3.23.1901.2014.pre.dat.nc")

  mrlon_t = get.var.ncdf(x,"lon") #Longitude
  mrlat_t = get.var.ncdf(x,"lat") #Latitude
  lonmin=-18
  lonmax=26
  latmin=3.4
  latmax=17

  mrlon=mrlon_t[mrlon_t>=lonmin&mrlon_t<=lonmax]
  lon=length(mrlon)
  lo1=which(mrlon_t==mrlon[1])

  mrlat=mrlat_t[mrlat_t>=latmin&mrlat_t<=latmax]
  lat=length(mrlat)
  la1=which(mrlat_t==mrlat[1])

  mpr= get.var.ncdf(x,varid=variable,start=c(lo1,la1,1),count=c(lon,lat,-1)) 
  mrtime=get.var.ncdf(x,"time")
  mrtime=mrtime/86400
  #dim1=c(dim(matrice))

  ts=length(mrtime) 

  print(paste("Nb days ",ts,sep=""))

  date1=paste(years[1],"-01-01",sep="")
  date2=paste(years[2],"-12-31",sep="")
  date=seq(as.Date(date1), as.Date(date2), "months")

  #for (t in 1:ts) {date[t]<-t}

  d1=lon*lat+1
  d2=ts+2
  mpr_sortie = array(NA, c(d1,d2))

  mpr_sortie[1,1]="latitude"
  mpr_sortie[1,2]="longitude"

  for (t in 1:ts) {mpr_sortie[1,t+2]<-as.character(date[t])}

  for (la in 1:lat) {
    for (lo in 1:lon) { row=(la-1)*lon+lo+1
                        mpr_sortie[row,1]<-mrlat[la]
                        mpr_sortie[row,2]<-mrlon[lo]

                        for (t in 1:ts) { rcol=t+2

                                          mpr_sortie[row,rcol]<-mpr[lo,la,t] 
                        }
    }
  }

  file=paste(folder,name,".txt",sep="")

  write.table(mpr_sortie, file = "file", append = FALSE, sep ="\t", eol = "\r", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names =FALSE, col.names =FALSE)

}#End for
```